# How can I use the arrow keys and the tab character in SSRS expression editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have Visual Studio 2010 Premium Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel. I've seen that others have this issue with Visual Studio 2012 as well.

When in the expression editor, I lose focus if I use the arrow keys or the TAB key. There is a workaround [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/790755/vs2012-when-editing-expression-of-textbox-left-arrow-key-on-keyboard-cause-cursor-to-disappear) involving holding ALT while you use the arrows, but I can't do a CTRL-over and I still can't use the TAB key. Not to mention that holding the ALT key is annoying.

This causes a decent slowdown of development, especially when I lose focus, hit the backspace key a couple times quickly, and all of a sudden I've canceled out of the Dataset formulas and lost all of my work.

Does anyone know how to use these keys without losing focus?

Comment: Do you have ReSharper installed? I think I noticed similar behavior starting with some add-in, but I don't recall which. It might have been one of the PowerTools.

Comment: It was the Power Tools extension! So much for power! Thank you so much. I guess I'll have to keep that disabled. I wish I'd asked this question a month ago. Answer and I'll accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is caused by some of the visual studio add-ins. OP had success with disabling the Productivity Power Tools, but in my VS 2012 install, disabling and uninstalling those didn't recover the use of the left arrow in the SSRS expression window. It may also be caused by JetBrains ResSharper.

Comment: I did also uninstall .NET Reflector, though if that was an issue, then both extensions are an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Jamie F's post should solve the problem in VS 2010, but the corresponding issue in VS 2012 is mentioned in [this connect bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/790755/vs2012-when-editing-expression-of-textbox-left-arrow-key-on-keyboard-cause-cursor-to-disappear) and is to be fixed in the next update of SSRS